# Automatically switch to test explorer window when running unit test

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit

In Visual Studio 2012 using NUnit, if I run a unit test by right-clicking its actual code and select "Run Tests" I then have to manually select the Test Explorer window to monitor its progress.

Is there a way to automatically make it switch to the Test Explorer window?